# C# get a value from a returned json object

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, object, nopcommerce

So im trying to check a value which is returned to me from an api call to active campaign.
Because I'm learning C# im not sure how to go about this.

So I use this code to send the api call and store the response in a variable:

```
var contactExists = acs.SendRequest("POST", getParameters1, postParameters1);
```

Then I output the response to the output wibndow in visual studio using this:

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(contactExists);
```

This returns this:

```
{"result_code":1,"result_message":"Success: Something is returned","result_output":"json"}
```

Now in C# how would I check the value of this `"result_code":1`

I came across [this anwswer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11395315/get-value-of-a-specific-object-property-in-c-sharp-without-knowing-the-class-beh) and checked the msdn but it's not making sense.

I also thought maybe contactExists.result_code would work but it doesn't.

Anyone know how to go about this.
Cheers

Comment: google along these lines: JsonConvert.DeserializeObject or this url may help: http://geekswithblogs.net/DavidHoerster/archive/2012/01/06/json.net-and-deserializing-anonymous-types.aspx

Comment: what is type of `acs` ?

Comment: @AliAdlavaran acs is active campaign service, based from this nuget package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/ActiveCampaign.Net/

Comment: And what is type of `contactExists` exactly ? maybe it is not `string`, so let me know.

Comment: @AliAdlavaran if I do this `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(contactExists.getType());` I get this result `System.String` in output window

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I deserialize JSON to a simple Dictionary<string,string> in ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207731/how-can-i-deserialize-json-to-a-simple-dictionarystring-string-in-asp-net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use the following peace of code. Here you can do this by using JObject class of Json.Net..

```
var jsonResult = acs.SendRequest("POST", getParameters1, postParameters1);
```

JObject contactExists = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonResult);

Now to access the properties from the above json object you can use like this:-

```
 int result_code = Convert.ToInt32(contactExists["result_code"]);
```

Comment: Hi Koderzzzz I try this but get red squiggle line under this `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(contactCheck);` Says Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject'

Comment: use like this JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(contactCheck);

Comment: Outstanding, it's working. Thanks for your help bud :D

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json):

```
var jsonResult = acs.SendRequest("POST", getParameters1, postParameters1);
dynamic contactExists = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonResult);
```

So you can easily use just like this:

```
int result_code = contactExists.result_code;
string result_message = contactExists.result_message;
```

I hope to be helpful for you :)

Comment: Thanks for your help Ali, it is throwing an exception when I try that. Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: ''Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' does not contain a definition for 'result_code''

Comment: Which version of `Json.NET` you are using?

Comment: Hmm im using version 9.0.1 of Newtonsoft Json

Comment: then the api does not return desired json string. check it with simple json string :`{"result_code":1,"result_message":"Success: Something is returned","result_output":"json"}` and let me know the result.

Answer (score 0):

Create an appropriate generic class

```
public class Response<T>
{
    public int result_code { get; set; }
    public string result_message { get; set; }
    public T result_output { get; set; }
}
```

Finally use the JSON Deserialization

```
var jsonResult = acs.SendRequest("POST", getParameters1, postParameters1);

var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response<string>>(jsonResult);
```